# Why I get runtime error when opening .wav files using python?

Tags: python, runtime-error

I am trying to run this code from GitHub https://github.com/facebookresearch/svoice using python in Spyder. I get this error RuntimeError: Error opening 'debug/mix/mix3.wav': System error.
I tried to change the wav files and rename them, I also tried older version of python, I changed the paths to complete paths, I checked the permission for the files   .. all trials failed .. Any help would be appreciated.
Unfortunately I keep running into a system error at some random point in the process:

```
    RuntimeError: Caught RuntimeError in DataLoader worker process 0.
Original Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\worker.py", line 287, in _worker_loop
    data = fetcher.fetch(index)
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\fetch.py", line 49, in fetch
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\fetch.py", line 49, in <listcomp>
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "C:\Users\svoice - Copy\svoice\data\data.py", line 61, in __getitem__
    mix_sig = self.mix_set[index]
  File "C:\Users\svoice - Copy\svoice\data\audio.py", line 77, in __getitem__
    out = torchaudio.load(str(file), frame_offset=frame_offset,
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torchaudio\backend\soundfile_backend.py", line 196, in load
    with soundfile.SoundFile(filepath, "r") as file_:
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\soundfile.py", line 629, in __init__
    self._file = self._open(file, mode_int, closefd)
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\soundfile.py", line 1183, in _open
    _error_check(_snd.sf_error(file_ptr),
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\soundfile.py", line 1357, in _error_check
    raise RuntimeError(prefix + _ffi.string(err_str).decode('utf-8', 'replace'))
RuntimeError: Error opening 'debug/mix/mix3.wav': System error.
```

Answer (score 0):

This runtime error 'Error opening .wav file' is fixed when I added the full path for each wav file.